# How to get the same motion in forward dynamics solution in Simulink?

Tags: matlab, simulink, inverse-kinematics

I am new to Simulink and I am having some problems on building and running multibody models.

Shortly, here is my problem.
I have designed a 2 joint,2 body system. I actuate each joint with position, velocity and acceleration data (array format) and the system works perfectly. I connected joint sensors to each joint, torque produced by joints are saved to workspace. I have the same model but it analyzes the system in forward dynamics. So, joints in this model are actuated by torques obtained from inverse dynamics model. But the motion comes out from the forward dynamics model is not same with the inverse dynamics model, even it is not similar, it is completely absurd. I think I have checked everything but for sure not "everything". Can anyone help me in this?!